# Android MNC API differences : Configuration.mnc / TelephonyManager.getSimOperator()

Tags: android, networking, configuration, operator-keyword, sim-card

I'm currently developing an app that requires distinct resources for a particular network operator in Morocco. The MNC of this operator is "00". According to the documentation I therefore used resources qualifiers such as :

- drawable-mcc604-mnc00
- drawable-mcc604-mnc00-hdpi
- etc.

However, when I tried this app on a device with this network operator the resources qualifiers did not work : the resources were still the "default" ones.

So I dig a little bit further and found a behavior that, from my understanding, seems uncanny. From what I saw, the SDK offers two ways of getting the MNC : via the Configuration API or via the TelephonyManager API.

- Via the Configuration API : the field mnc is 0 (and not the so-called MNC_ZERO), which according to the documentation is not "0" per se but rather undefined (though field mcc is 604 which is correct)
- Via the TelephonyManager API : the method getSimOperator() returns "60400" which is 100% correct

So it raises a few questions :

1. Why do those API (that seems semantically identical) have different results?
2. Why does the field Configuration.mnc is an int and not a String? Because I'm not sure how you can represent "00" in a int field... or how you can make the difference between "00" and "000" or even between  "01" and "001" which are all valid and distinct MNC values.
3. And most importantly, on which of these API (if not a third one) Android relies when it comes to decide whether it should use the defaults resources or the qualified resources?

   - Note1 : I tested the same thing with another particular operator network and it worked fine so it seems the MNC "00" is the main concern here
   - Note2 : I'm testing from France therefore I'm in roaming condition

Thanks in advance for the heads-up.

Answer (score 1):

Try MNC_ZERO.
It is a special case.
Refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#MNC_ZERO

Comment: Well that does not answer a thing... or does it ? What do you mean exactly by "try MNC_ZERO" ? Anyway I'm well aware of this specificity though I didn't mention it in the initial post.

Comment: It is the answer ant it is work. Maybe I can find the sample code for you but later.